# Reference DLL is not being replaced

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

My problem is that VS 2017 is not replacing my reference DLL.

1. Project 1 (class Library) holds 2 DLLs that the project is referenced to. those DLL's are vendor DLL(ALM OTA)
   the files have versions and project 1 working with this files. I am running the build and I have on bin\debug the DLL file of project 1
2. Project 2(.net web API) is referenced to projec1.dll and uses methods and models from project1.dll

Once I am replacing the files that project 1 is referenced to(ALM OTA v2) and creating new build on project1 and adding project1.dll to project 2, the files are not being changed I am not getting the new
project1.dll.

- that worked for me before many times with this projects from some reason it stopped.
- the copy local in project 1 (class Library) is set to false and cant be modified ,in project 2 it is
  true.
- tried to Change the files location bust still not working

please HELP..

Comment: Are you able to ref the ALM OTA stuff via nuget?

Comment: it is not nuget , it is simple dll that are coming form different application.

Comment: You have no problem with quoting before, but this time there is a problem. According to your description, there is nothing wrong with your quoting operation on the file, so I think it may be caused by the operation that you did not notice. You can also refer to other people's add reference operation. Here is the link: [https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/project-reference-vs-dll-reference-in-visual-studio/](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/project-reference-vs-dll-reference-in-visual-studio/)